# AudioRecord: bits per sample

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-audiorecord

[AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) has methods to get the data as byte[], short[] and ByteBuffer.

I can't see anything in the documentation which says how many bits per sample are used.

Can it record in 8 bits? 16 bits? More? (How is this determined/set?)

Can the method which returns byte[]/ByteBuffer be used for 16 bit samples, and how would the most significant byte / least significant byte be differentated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably this is what [`getAudioFormat()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#getAudioFormat%28%29) tells you...

Comment: A thank you, yes it was right in front of me! So I presume then that the read() methods that provide a ByteBuffer and byte[] can't be used for 16 bit PCM? And what determines whether it's recorded in 8 or 16 bit?